# Contact form - Go to page

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have a contact form which send an e-mail to me when someone fills the fields and clicks "send".

Now I need something like a "thank you" page, on that page I need to load a piece of code to track it.

This is the code what I have now:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact.php" role="form" class="wpcf7">
```

And this is the button:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'contact', 'button-verstuur')";>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send wpcf7-submit" value="Verstuur">
   </a>
</div>
```

What I want to do is redirect the page after someone click the "send" button. But only if all the required fields are filled in. At the moment it checks if the required fields are filled. So the redirect to a "thank you" page should only work when the required fields are filled.

Hope someone can help me with this one.

Edit:

This is the PHP code

```
    // configure
$from = 'Contactform <myform@forming.com>';
$sendTo = '<sendto@myself.com>';
$subject = 'New message';
$fields = array('name' => 'Naam', 'surname' => 'Achternaam', 'phone' => 'Telefoonnummer', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Bericht'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Your message is sent successfully!';
$errorMessage = 'Error, please try again later.';

// let's do the sending

if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '') try
{
    $emailText = "Uw heeft een nieuw bericht\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

The HTML form:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact.php" role="form" class="wpcf7">

       <div class="messages"></div>

           <div class="controls">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name"><span class="required">*</span> Naam:</label>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="wpcf7-text" required="required" data-error="Uw naam is verplicht">
                    </span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email"><span class="required">*</span> E-mail:</label>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="wpcf7-text" required="required" data-error="Een geldig e-mailadres is verplicht">
                    </span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_phone"><span class="required">*</span> Telefoonnummer:</label>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-url">
                        <input id="form_phone" type="text" name="phone" class="wpcf7-text">
                    </span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message"><span class="required">*</span> Bericht:</label>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="wpcf7-textarea" rows="4" required="required" data-error="U moet een bericht invullen"></textarea>
                    </span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group antispam">
                    <label for="form_phonee"><span class="required">*</span> Veld leeg laten:</label>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-url">
                        <input id="form_phonee" type="text" name="url" class="wpcf7-text">
                    </span>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12"><a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'contact', 'button-verstuur')";>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send wpcf7-submit" value="Verstuur"></a>
                </div>

            </div>

   </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you posting using Ajax? Where is the PHP code that receives the posted form? Please add all relevant code and information. Looking at the form class, I'm guessing that you're using Wordpress and Contact Form 7?

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson I've added the PHP code above. I've tried to put the tag code into the success message, but I don't know how to put javascript inside it.

Comment: can you post the html form ?

Comment: @BRjava Yes, added :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi best option is to check each variable is empty or not . If there are errors , load you html with errors, else continue to your code
Ex:

```
        $form_nameErr = $form_emailErr = $form_phoneErr = $form_messageErr = $form_phoneeErr = "";
        if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '') try
        {
            $emailText = "Uw heeft een nieuw bericht\n=============================\n";

            if(!empty($_POST['form_name'])){
                $emailText .= $_POST['form_name']."\n";
            }else{
                $form_nameErr = "Form Name required";
            }

            if(!empty($_POST['form_email'])){
                $emailText .= $_POST['form_email']."\n";
            }else{
                $form_emailErr = "Email Text required";
            }
        }
if(!empty($form_nameErr) && !empty($form_emailErr) && !empty($form_phoneErr) && !empty($form_messageErr) )){
     mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
//TO redirect
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/thankyou.php"); 
exit();

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}else{
            //load you html with error variables
}
```

your html should contain

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name"><span class="required">*</span> Naam:</label>
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="wpcf7-text" required="required" data-error="Uw naam is verplicht">
                    </span>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
                </div>
```

define error style
Refer : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think there is a little miscommunication. The form is already working and is checking if field are empty, the only thing I need it to redirect the page to another page after success :)

Comment: I`ve updated answer, use redirect after email send function

Comment: if it`s the correct answer, could you accept the answer ?